# Force reconnect on sshfs drive mounted via fstab

Tags: filesystems, fstab, sshfs

I have a remote sshfs drive that I use on a daily basis. I previously executed the following command every time I booted up my computer.

```
sshfs -o Ciphers=arcfour -o Compression=no -o reconnect remote:dev ~/dev
```

Obviously, it's not super convenient to do that by hand every time, so I thought I'd just add the remote to my file systems table. I am unfamiliar with how fstab is formatted, but after a bit of reading on a few technical "how-to" blogs, I settled on including the following line in my `/etc/fstab` file.

```
sshfs#wbarlow@remote:/home/wbarlow/dev /home/wbarlow/dev fuse defaults,users,idmap=user 0 0
```

Unfortunately, if there is a blip in the network, the drive sometimes goes down. This happens maybe once per day -- and when I try to manually reconnect (by clicking on the drive in nautilus), I'm given a message that says "Transport endpoint is not connected.".

My primary question is this: **how can I bring the `-o reconnect` option that I used in the terminal command into my fstab file?** I believe that would prevent the drive disconnect due to blips.

Also, I chose that cipher because it's the quickest one my remote server supports (I think), and removed compression because the wired gigabit network is faster than the time taken by the CPU to compress stuff. It would be great if I could pull those options into my fstab as well, but I can live without them.

Here is my Kernel/OS/architecture info:

```
[wbarlow ~]$ uname -r
4.1.3-200.fc22.x86_64
```

Comment: So the command that you reference at the top of your post that you have to manually enter does the trick as far as you're concerned - with the obvious point that you have to retype it every time you boot?

Comment: @datUser yes, and if you're going to suggest i add it to auto-run on login, i suppose i could do that. using fstab seems cleaner, though.

Comment: Well you're reading my mind :-) - keep that in you're back pocket if there is no way to add the additional flags to the `fstab` entry

Comment: NOTE `arcfour` is no longer considered "safe".  There's a replacement `chacha20-poly1305`, it seems to be slower.  However you might find `aes128-gcm@openssh.com` is actually faster than either, if both ends have cpu with AES-NI instruction set.  http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10994/4074

Comment: @sourcejedi thank you. i'll look into other ciphers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To include the options you want, you should modify your fstab entry as shown below.  Be careful, as adding an option that doesn't actually exist will cause your system not to boot.

```
sshfs#wbarlow@remote:/home/wbarlow/dev /home/wbarlow/dev fuse defaults,users,noauto,idmap=user,Ciphers=arcfour,Compression=no,reconnect 0 0
```

I tested it by

1. Inspecting the output of `ps|grep ssh`
2. Running `kill ssh` didn't kill the mount.

I took the liberty of adding the `noauto` option.  This requests that the mount won't happen automatically, so that any failure will not stop the boot process (particularly when using systemd).  It relies on you having a convenient way of running `mount`.  Hopefully your filemanager will provide this, otherwise it defeats the point...

Another possibility is the `nofail` option.  This option requests a successful boot even if this filesystem fails to mount "this device if it does not exist".  Unfortunately we found sshfs/fuse has not implemented this option.  Ironically, using the `nofail` option here will guarantee failure.

---

The docs (`man fstab`) describe the fourth field of an fstab entry:

> **The fourth field** (fs_mntops)
>
> This  field  describes  the  mount  options  associated with the filesystem.
>
> It is formatted as a comma-separated list of options. It  contains at least the type of mount (ro or rw), plus any additional options appropriate to the filesystem  type  (including  performance-tuning options). For details, see mount(8) or swapon(8).
>
> Basic filesystem-independent options are:
>
> - **defaults** use  default  options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.
> - **noauto** do not mount when "mount -a"  is  given  (e.g.,  at  boot time).
> - **user** allow a user to mount.
> - **owner** allow device owner to mount.
> - **comment** or **x-<name>** for use by fstab-maintaining programs.
> - **nofail** do  not  report  errors  for  this  device if it does not exist.

Options which are completely filesystem-independent are handled by fstab.  Other options are passed to the filesystem-specific command (in this case, sshfs).

Comment: so, like, `defaults,users,idmap=user,reconnect`? the man pages for fstab seem to describe that field as an fstab-specific options list, rather than options associated with the filesystem's mounting command.

Comment: yes.  there are some generic options like `users` but the rest are passed to the specific filesystem.

Comment: is there a way i can confirm that the options are actually being used rather than thrown away? is there an fstab log file where a warning might be printed if i had put an option that doesn't exist?

Comment: i put a gibberish option in and the system failed to boot, then i put my sshfs options in and it booted fine, so i guess this answers my question. i'm a bit embarrassed i didn't realize that from the docs.

Comment: i've suggested an edit to add some documentation to the answer. i'll award the bounty as soon as the timer allows me to do so.

Comment: looks like it went through.

Comment: if i copy-paste the line as you have it, the system boots fine but clicking on the drive in my file explorer (in order to mount it) presents me with an error message: "fuse: unknown option 'nofail'". i have no idea why the option is being passed onto fuse, as the documentation clearly identifies it as one of the fs-independent options. mounting works as expected only if i remove the `nofail` option. also, (re: noauto option) the drive has *never* auto-mounted. it is listed among my drives but doesn't mount unless i click on it, like my ntfs drive. i thought this was just how fuse drives work.

Comment: Ok, I would use `noauto` then.  Lol @ `man mount`: `The command mount does not pass the mount options unbindable,  runbindable,  private, rprivate, slave, rslave, shared, rshared, auto, noauto,comment, x-*, loop, offset and sizelimit to the mount.<suffix> helpers.  All other options are used in a comma-separated list as argument to the -o option.`